# Android MediaSession not displaying album art as lockscreen background

Tags: java, android

After loading in all the current song information to the session metadata, the album art refuses to load on the lockscreen. I know for a fact that the bitmap is valid because I use the same resource for the notification art. I've also tried using just a static resource, but no luck. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
        String more;
    if (shuffled) {
        more = Integer.toString(shufflePosition+1) + "/" + Integer.toString(playlist.size());
    }
    else{
        more = Integer.toString(position+1) + "/" + Integer.toString(playlist.size());
    }

    int notificationAction = android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause;//needs to be initialized

    //Build a new notification according to the current state of the MediaPlayer
    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
        notificationAction = android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause;
    } else{
        notificationAction = android.R.drawable.ic_media_play;
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),np.getArt());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.mipmap.empty_track);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mSession.setMetadata(new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
            .putBitmap(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ART, bitmap)
            .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, np.getArtist())
            .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM, np.getAlbum())
            .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, np.getTrack())
            .build());

    Notification notification;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        notification = new android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.empty_artist)
                .setShowWhen(false)
                .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(android.R.drawable.ic_media_previous, "Previous", pendingPrev).build())
                .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(notificationAction, "Pause", pendingPlay).build())
                .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(android.R.drawable.ic_media_next, "Next", pendingNext).build())
                .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
                .setContentTitle(np.getTrack())
                .setContentText(np.getArtist())
                .setSubText(more)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                .setContentIntent(launchActivity)
                .setStyle(new android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                        .setMediaSession(mSession.getSessionToken()).setShowActionsInCompactView(0,1,2))
                .build();
    } else {
        notification = new android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.empty_artist)
                .setShowWhen(false)
                .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(android.R.drawable.ic_media_previous, "Previous", pendingPrev).build())
                .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(notificationAction, "Pause", pendingPlay).build())
                .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(android.R.drawable.ic_media_next, "Next", pendingNext).build())
                .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
                .setContentTitle(np.getTrack())
                .setContentText(np.getArtist())
                .setSubText(more)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                .setContentIntent(launchActivity)
                .setStyle(new android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                        .setMediaSession(mSession.getSessionToken())
                        .setShowActionsInCompactView(0,1,2))
                .build();
    }
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(001, notification);
    startForeground(001, notification);
```

Comment: Don't you have to set the `PlaybackState` as well as the metadata?

Answer (score 3):

As per the [Working with a Media Session documentation page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/working-with-a-media-session.html#album_artwork):

> In Android 4.0 (API level 14) and greater, the background of the lock screen displays your album artwork - but only if the media session metadata includes a background bitmap.

You must set a background Bitmap in your `MediaMetadataCompat` by using [`putBitmap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/MediaMetadataCompat.Builder.html#putBitmap(java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.Bitmap)) with either [`METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/MediaMetadataCompat.html#METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART) or [`METADATA_KEY_ART`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/MediaMetadataCompat.html#METADATA_KEY_ART)

Comment: @ianhannniballake - let's say i have a playlist for 100 tracks, this will consume a lot of memory? can't URI be used?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use playbackstate after 3 days i found this one

```
    public void pausePlayer() {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            startForeground(false);
            ((MainActivity) context).notificationUpdated(false);
            isPlay = false;
            playbackStateCompat.setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP);
            playbackStateCompat.setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED, mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition(), 1.0f, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            mediaSession.setPlaybackState(playbackStateCompat.build());
        }
    }
```

```
  mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(currentSong.getUrl()));
        mediaSession.setMetadata(getMetadata());
        playbackStateCompat.setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP);
        playbackStateCompat.setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING, mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition(), 1.0f, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        mediaSession.setPlaybackState(playbackStateCompat.build());
        mediaPlayer.start();
```